# How do I find out how PHP was installed

Tags: ubuntu, php

Is there a way to work out if PHP was installed as part of a generic apt-get package, compiled from source or installed some other way on Ubuntu?

I need to recompile it with some more options and I want to try and follow the correct upgrade path.

Comment: If you're going to compile it with different options, consider making a package of your version, so that it can be tracked in the future...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if the package is installed with:

```
 dpkg -l |grep php
```

and can check if the files on your system is consistent with the package with

```
 debsums packagename
```

from this you can have some clues about the origin of the package.

Answer (score 4):

you may want to run as root

```
root@machine:~# dpkg -l php5 (or whatever version you have)
```

if php was installed using packet manager, this command will retun some thing like

```
root@machine:~# dpkg -l php5
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Cfg-files/Unpacked/Failed-cfg/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                   Version                                Description
+++-======================================-======================================-============================================================================================
ii  php5                                   5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10                      server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
```

notice the content of the first comumn wich is **"ii"**
else , you will have the same output but with the first column containing **"un"** instead of **ii**